# Has someone tried to open MsWord for mac application from PowerShell for mac script?

Tags: ms-office

I've been trying to open my Word application from PowerShell script on my mac.

If it would be a PC I had done this as below:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.application
```

But as we don't have a COM on mac what is the method to control Word from PowerShell on mac?

Has anyone succeeded in doing so?

If PowerShell cannot do this what is the path to go forward? Is it possible at all?

Comment: There is no "PowerShell" on macOS. I can only guess that you are talking about a command line which would be the Terminal app on a Mac. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @agarza One can easily install and use PowerShell on macOS, I imagine OP has done that.

Comment: @grg Huh... I thought that was only for Windows. Learn something every day. My apologies.